# Showing Sub tables in Access table from relationship

Tags: ms-access

I have a table in Access that has two tables connected through a relationship.  In the table (parent) there is a + next to each row and it shows the linked data from only one of the tables.  Can I show more than one table in a single table in Access.  Only one of the tables has a primary key because the other tables have duplicates.

I can not remove these duplicates, and this may be the issue, I want to know if there is a work around.  Also i am new to relational databases in Access, sorry if i am not asking the right question,  so I am not sure about foreign keys or how to set one if that is required or how to set a primary key to a field with duplicates.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this: [Access Subdatasheet](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Add-a-subdatasheet-900d1d30-5ea2-4e47-80a7-ddcb87a53d14?CorrelationId=f32cc0c2-d693-4480-ac2b-a9ac47d5f01d&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US)

You can only have one subdatasheet appearing per table.